# My application in Laravel and vuejs, when I deploy to a VPS, in vue components API call goes to the localhost instead of my server IP address

Tags: laravel, deployment, vuejs2, vps

In some vue components I have http request using axios to the server to access this route http://35.184.16.20/api/location-type the problem is; instead of that route http request goes to http://localhost:8000/api/location-type.

in vue part in the app.js file I have //axios.defaults.baseURL='http://localhost:8000/api/'; axios.defaults.baseURL='http://35.184.16.20/api/'; when I push to server I'll comment out the localhost and uncomment the serve ip. It was working fine, after my server ip address changed this problem raised.

I changed to production in the .env but still having the problem.

this is .env in the life server

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:hkzyStjgzyyDQk7DjIK0nXHOIUQ/5mUYcM0fQP6hCnE=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://35.184.16.20

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=db_password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=myid
PUSHER_APP_KEY=somekey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=somesecret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: can the base url of vuejs

Comment: You are showing your Laravel env file, which defines the environment for the backend, but you should look into your Vue's env files, since you're problem occurs in the JavaScript of your frontend.

Comment: I couldn't find out why this problems raised, but I did reset my branch to a commit before this problem happened. thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find out why this problems raised, but I did reset my branch to a commit before this problem happened. thanks for your comments.